# Exception in @Future Method - System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable

Tags: apex, trigger, asynchronous

I am facing error in one of future method (calling from trigger handler). This error occurs when integration event submit these record in bulk but when i am doing this from UI i do not get this error. I am trying to recreate scenario but it work fine when i do from UI. Can anyone please help me on this.

> Failed to invoke future method 'public static void getOpportunity(Set, Set)' on class 'OpportunityCloning_Handler' for job id '7070e00004gqK5G'
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable: The record you are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is currently being modified by another user. Please try again.
>
> Class.OpportunityCloning_Handler.getValidOpportunity: line 498, column 1
>   Class.OpportunityCloning_Handler.CreateOpportunity: line 553, column 1

My Future method is

```
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void getOpportunity(set<id> oppId,set<String> quoteIds){
        CreateOpportunity(oppId,quoteIds);
    }


public static void CreateOpportunity(set<id> oppId,set<String> quoteIds){ 
    list<Opportunity> Opportunities1 =  getValidOpportunity(oppId, quoteIds);  // This has query on Opp and related Object with FOR UPDATE

}

public static list<Opportunity> getValidOpportunity(set<id> oppId,set<String> quoteIds)
    {
        list<Opportunity> Opportunities1 = null; 

        if(quoteIds == null || quoteIds.isEmpty())
        {
            Opportunities1 = 
                [select id,Account__c,Account__r.Unique_Identifier__c,Account__r.bitLink__c,Account__r.eEnrollment__c,Account__r.segment__c,
                 (Select P_Location_Contact__c,P_Location_Contact__r.P_Contact__c, P_Location__c,
                  From Q_Opportunity_Producer_Filters__r) 
                 (SELECT Id, Comment__c, Type__c FROM Comments__r WHERE Type__c = 'Comments for ASS')
                 from Opportunity where (id IN: oppId) AND  RecordType.Name != 'Pre Sale'
                 AND (Quote_Status_changed_by__c ='Manual' OR Quote_Status_changed_by__c ='Integration Event')AND IsASSCreated__c = false FOR UPDATE];    
        }else{
            Opportunities1 = 
                [select id,Account__c,Account__r.Unique_Identifier__c,Account__r.bitLink__c,Account__r.eEnrollment__c,Account__r.segment__c,
                 (Select P_Location_Contact__c,P_Location_Contact__r.P_Contact__c, P_Location__c,
                  From Q_Opportunity_Producer_Filters__r) ,
                 (SELECT Id, Comment__c, Type__c FROM Comments__r WHERE Type__c = 'Comments for ASS')
                 from Opportunity where (id IN: oppId OR QuoteID1__c IN:quoteIds) AND  RecordType.Name != 'Pre Sale'
                 AND (Quote_Status_changed_by__c ='Manual' OR   Quote_Status_changed_by__c ='Integration Event' ) AND IsPSSCreated__c = false FOR UPDATE];    
        }


        return Opportunities1 ;
    }
```

Trigger calling getopportunity method :

```
try{
            list<Integ_Exceptions__c > lstErros = new list<Integ_Exceptions__c >();
            set<Id> OppId = new set<id>();
            set<String> QuoteIds = new set<String>();

            for(Opportunity opp : newRecords){

        //Code-Logic

            }
            if((OppId!=null && OppId.size()>0) && sObj_Utility.isopptyCreated == false) {
                OpportunityCloning_Handler.getOpportunity(OppId,QuoteIds);
            }
            if(lstErros.size() > 0)
                Database.insert(lstErros ,false);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Integ_Exceptions__c err = new Integ_Exceptions__c( Area__c = 'AMM Creation', 
                                                    Message__c = e.getMessage() +'\n' + e.getStackTraceString() );
            insert err ;  
            }
       }

    }
```

Comment: Did you order by ParentId in your query ?

Comment: No, there is no order by. I am using sub query.

Comment: If possible can you share you `getValidOpportunity()` it looks like that's where the error is originating from!

Comment: It was selecting many fields so i removed some fields

Comment: Are you calling the future method more than once in the trigger, or in more than one trigger event? Could the trigger be getting re-fired by a workflow rule or process, or trigger recursion? Can you show us the call from the trigger?

Comment: This method is called once it create Opportunity record then opportunity  before Before/After Opportunity trigger  get fire. do you mean some process/trigger/WF rule firing same method in same transaction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have a different species of lock contention than other questions we've seen recently about *implicit* lock contention, leading to `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` errors. What you have is a situation where two elements of your application are attempting to establish an explicit lock using a SOQL `FOR UPDATE` clause at the same time, resulting in one of the lock attempts timing out before the other is released.

When you establish that lock, it persists until your transaction closes. Other transactions seeking to lock the same object can time out with a `QueryException` if the lock is [held too long](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm):

> If you attempt to lock a record currently locked by another client, your process waits for the lock to be released before acquiring a new lock. If the lock isn’t released within 10 seconds, you will get a `QueryException`.

Based on the fact that you are establishing these locks in an `@future` method called from a trigger, to me the most likely theory that occurs is that said `@future` method is being called twice, and the two enqueued jobs are being executed by the system at close enough to the same time to contend with one another for the locks.

Why might the job be enqueued twice? Well, there's a number of reasons why the same trigger can be fired multiple times for the same records. Based on your note that you observe this issue only with bulk data loads, it could be that your trigger code is poorly bulkified and fires the future method more than once for the same inbound record set. Or your bulk input may result in a different code path being executed that's more vulnerable to a recursion issue.

Many of the possible paths also involve some species of trigger recursion, either from explicit DML operations your code executes or from a Process or Workflow Rule that runs later in the [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) and causes the trigger to run a second time. We don't know, because we don't even see how you call this method from the trigger, but that's the first culprit I would be looking at myself.

### Example

Here's an example I created in a Trailhead Playground org. This is a great example because *I messed it up* - I set out to show you how a future method would get called twice, and I actually got it called *four* times because of trigger recursion I didn't realize was there.

#### Trigger

```
trigger AccountsTrigger on Account (after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete, before delete, before insert, before update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        TestQ244395.runFuture();
    }
    
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        TestQ244395.runFuture();
    }
}
```

Here, we call an `@future` method twice, once in a trigger before event and once in an after event. These are enqueued in the same transaction, but each will execute in its own, separate transaction.

#### Class

```
public class TestQ244395 {
    @future
    public static void runFuture() {
        System.debug('In future method');
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't demonstrate lock contention - I'm just aiming at showing one route whereby your future method could be called more than you think it will be.

#### Log Entries

Here's what the log entries look like after I run an Execute Anonymous with this code:

```
insert new Account(Name='TestQ244395');
```

[image]

What I wanted to show you was two `FutureHandler` log entries as a guide-post to identifying if this is really the source of your issue. Instead, I got four entries. Why? Let's look at the `executeAnonymous` entry.

I'm not going to include the whole log for brevity, so here's a screen shot filtered by `CODE_UNIT` so we can see where Salesforce starts executing each code unit.

[image]

Notice here the critical line

> 21:05:56:158 CODE_UNIT_STARTED [EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Account

followed by

> 21:05:56:636 CODE_UNIT_STARTED [EXTERNAL]|01q41000001d3z6|AccountsTrigger on Account trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/AccountsTrigger
>
> 21:05:56:661 CODE_UNIT_STARTED [EXTERNAL]|01q41000001d3z6|AccountsTrigger on Account trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/AccountsTrigger

I forgot that this org had a workflow rule that fired on Account creation. When the workflow rule went off, it performed an update that resulted in firing my trigger *again* - meaning that I got a total of *four* future methods firing.

This is where you'd start approaching your issue, I think, to determine whether my surmise that this is what's happening is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed for explaining in details. I have added some logic. I am not sure why Try and catch is not working here. I am receiving email for exception even we have catch block. I am not sure if I anything is missing in current logic

Comment: You can't catch an exception thrown in a future method in the code that enqueues that future method. They are running in separate transactions.

Comment: Ok, Can i add try and catch in getOpportunity method. something like try { CreateOpportunity(oppId,quoteIds);} catch {}.

Comment: I would expect that to suppress the error, but that doesn't necessarily mean the functionality is working correctly. The true fix is going to be finding the cause of the lock contention. That's code architecture-level or even org architecture-level problem that is tricky to solve without being hands-on in your org. I'll add some suggestions for tracing the source when I get home later, but I don't know that I can offer you an easy solution - just proposals for how to locate the ultimate problem.

Comment: Its late but want to mention that david solution helped me to get this issue.  Issue was in trigger which is calling future method. Same future method getting called twice in same transaction and due to log size it was not appearing in debug log. After so much effort i was able to get it. Thanks David for help and suggestion. !!